# How to change permissions for file on sFTP server using phpseclib?

Tags: php, sftp, phpseclib

I tried `$sftp->chmod('0755', "file.zip");` and `$sftp->chmod('0755', "file.zip");`

But in both cases the permission has been set to 363 instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

0755 and '0755' are not the same thing as demonstrated thusly:

```
<?php echo '0755' == 0755 ? 'equal' : 'not equal'; ?>;
```

Per that, try removing the single quotes around 0755.

The reason phpseclib expects permissions to be represented as an octal value ('0755' is cast to a decimal value - not an octal one) is because that's how `ftp_chmod` does it and that's what `Net_SFTP::chmod()` is modeled after.  (actually, pretty much all of phpseclib's SFTP API is modeled after PHP's FTP extension API)

Answer (score 1):

At a guess the permissions are 1363. In other words octal(755). It's a complete guess, but I would suggest that the chmod function is taking a decimal mode, rather than an octal one.

Comment: A look through the file at http://www.frostjedi.com/terra/SFTP.txt tells me it is indeed binary. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$sftp->chmod(0755, $file);
```

You should not input permissions into the phpseclib `chmod()` function as a string.

Comment: Please always explain your short answers.